# difference in "compare" cluster algorithms and its memberships

Tags: r, compare, cluster-analysis, igraph

what is the difference between the "compare" command applied to cluster algorithms, and to its application to cluster memberships, in igraph.

As states manual page:

```
compare (sg, le, method = "rand")    
compare (membership (sg), membership (le))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you read the documentation for the `compare`, it's format is :

```
compare(comm1, comm2, method = c("vi", "nmi", "split.join", "rand", "adjusted.rand"))
```

The documentation for `comm1` and `comm2` mentions the following:

> **comm1** : A communities object containing a community structure; or a numeric vector, the membership vector of the first community structure. The membership vector should contain the community id of each vertex, the numbering of the communities starts with one.

The complete code mentioned towards the end is

```
g <- make_graph("Zachary")
sg <- cluster_spinglass(g)
le <- cluster_leading_eigen(g)
compare(sg, le, method="rand")
compare(membership(sg), membership(le))
```

**Now in the first case**:
`compare(sg, le, method="rand")`

`sg` and `le` are the cluster objects themselves, i.e. they are results of [community detection via spin-glass model](https://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_spinglass.html) and  [community detetection by calculating the leading non-negative eigenvector of the modularity matrix of the graph](https://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_leading_eigen.html) respectively. In short, both contain community structures of the data.

**Now in the second case**:
`compare(membership(sg), membership(le))`

This uses `membership` which does the following:

> membership gives the division of the vertices, into communities. It returns a numeric vector, one value for each vertex, the id of its community. Community ids start from one. Note that some algorithms calculate the complete (or incomplete) hierarchical structure of the communities, and not just a single partitioning. For these algorithms typically the membership for the highest modularity value is returned, but see also the manual pages of the individual algorithms

You can read more about the function [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html).
So as you can see, this returns a numeric vector containing the membership information of each vertex, which is the second type of value that is permitted in the `comm1` and `comm2` parameter of `compare` function.

Hence, both statements are essentially same. They are just different ways of accomplishing the same thing.

If you run the code given towards the end of the documentation, you will see the following:

```
> g <- make_graph("Zachary")
> sg <- cluster_spinglass(g)
> le <- cluster_leading_eigen(g)
> compare(sg, le, method="rand")
[1] 0.9500891
> compare(membership(sg), membership(le))
[1] 0.2765712
```

The difference in results is because the `method` attribute is set to `rand` in the first call. If you assign the `method` attribute in the second call as well, you will see the exact same results:

```
> g <- make_graph("Zachary")
> sg <- cluster_spinglass(g)
> le <- cluster_leading_eigen(g)
> compare(sg, le, method="rand")
[1] 0.9500891
> compare(membership(sg), membership(le), method="rand")
[1] 0.9500891
```

As you can see, both provide identical results.

**Reference:**

- https://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_spinglass.html
- https://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html
- https://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_leading_eigen.html
- https://igraph.org/r/doc/compare.html